# Code requirement evasion

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

How should members of the community deal with [posts which attempt to circumvent the "code required" constraint when posting a jsFiddle link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381364/q-alpaca-js-form-wont-render-with-bootstrap-3-0-and-fuel-ux)?

This is quite obviously an attempt at evading the filter, but should these be flagged? Edited? Commented on in any way?

Comment: Just downvote and move on. *If you are feeling charitable*, edit the post to include the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downvote them because they don't contain the necessary information to solve the problem. Close the question as offtopic > "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.".

Emphasis says it all. It must be in the question. A question should be readable without the link, and therefore the question is useless. It has to be edited to be useful. It is the responsibility of OP to do this.

Comment: Every single time I marked such a question as such, my flag either gets rejected or disputed, since the first thing one reads is "off-topic" which does not really cover the essence, such a question could become acceptable when more information is added. A new category would be helpful, e.g. "Incomplete" rather than "off-topic" for questions lacking a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.